# Google Sheets formula to leave cell empty based on conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having issues with this formula:

=ARRAYFORMULA("WORD"&" "&sheet1!$B$20&" "&'sheet2'!A2:A&" "&sheet1!$B$17&'sheet2'!B2:B)

What I want is to leave empty cell if there is no data available in sheet 2 and when the data is added in the sheet (sheet2) the formula auto populates the results in the third sheet, where the formula is placed.
Tried with If function, but I'm getting Errors.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('sheet2'!A2:A="","","WORD"&" "&sheet1!$B$20&" "&'sheet2'!A2:A&" "&sheet1!$B$17&'sheet2'!B2:B))
```